# If you buy asset in one country that is 2/3 owned by an investor in another country, what currency do you pay in?

Tags: investing, currency, international, corporate-acquisition

I'm in the US. I want to acquire a UK-registered firm that is 2/3 owned by foreign investors. The UK firm is private.

What currency must I use to make the purchase? Where is it written that this is so?

**Rationale**

I've got dollars. I want to acquire a UK company. I want to assess how the dollar-GBP exchange rate will effect my acquiring this UK asset.

GBP exchange rate has been at a 30-year low. So I would guess this asset is going cheap now, because when I exchange my dollars into GBP to buy the company, I get more GBP for my buck.

To complicate things, the company I want to buy is majority-owned by an investment fund in Luxembourg. The fund is owned by another firm registered in an EU country. So perhaps my assumption that UK assets are cheap when the exchange rate is low doesn't apply? Please do correct me if my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Unclear. Are you asking about buying some of the firm's publicly traded shares on some stock exchange, or else a complete acquisition of the firm? Is it private?

Comment: It's clear enough! If you buy a firm, you acquire it. If there's a difference in what currency you pay according to whether it is public or private, perhaps you would be kind enough to elaborate?

Comment: Ah, that depends on what you agree on? You MUST do nothing in this regard - you CAN do anything as long as both parties agree. YOu can pay in other property (swaps), you can pay in any way agreed upon in the contract.

Comment: Ah. I must then be more specific. Let us assume cash. Because what I mean then is, what currency is used to determine the value in $ of the company being bought?

Comment: @markling If it is a private firm, you can negotiate all conditions with the seller: way of being paid, amout to be paid, time for payment etc. If it is a pubic firm and you buy shares via an exchange, the rules of this exchange are applied.

Comment: So, what does the contract say?

Comment: It's a hypothetical question. My powers of imagination don't extend to contractual details.

Comment: If whomever holds the company now wishes to sell for 3.4 lightly used cheese graters, then that is the currency you need. You might want to bid 4, just to avoid carrying the .6 cheese grater.

Comment: ha! mark the questioner down for not knowing the answer to the question before asking it.

Answer (score 6):

That entity owns 2/3 of the company. You can't force them to sell. So the negotiated price will have to be stated in some units that both sides can accept. You will have to decide if they insist on a specific unit of measure that you can accept it. If the price is in a units other than your standard units of money, you will be responsible for estimating the costs involved in the conversion to their units.

I would be surprised if this is covered in UK , EU or US law. Though if they are a public company with stocks sold on a particular stock market, that might be the determining factor. But when entire companies are bought and sold the price doesn't have to be all cash, sometimes the result is that the old owners end up with shares in the new combined company. Everything is negotiable.

An edit was made to the question to clarify it is a private company and a comment makes it clear it is hypothetical.

That doesn't change the first part of the answer. Somebody owns it. You want to buy it. You need to negotiate the price. You may even need to pay for the company over a period of time. If you feel that it is best for you to state the term in GBP then do so. If they would like to state the price in Euros they will let you know. That decision regarding the monetary units might be the first decision that needs to be made during the negotiations.

Comment: This helped clarify the question, thanks. The question is about currency exchange in assessing asset value.

Comment: I've clarified the question further. Would you please consider reviewing your answer?

Comment: You edited question didn't change my answer. Everything is a negotiation.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a UK company would use Pounds sterling for their accounts and operations, but if they did a lot of business in Europe (or their current majority owners insisted) they could use Euro.  The UK allow taxes to be paid in Euro should a company or individual decide to do so.

There is no requirement that a company use a particular currency, though there could be barriers if they decide to use something unusual (e.g. working out their accounts for tax purposes).  However as a result of EU integration, Euro should be almost as workable as GBP.

You might be able to get a sense by downloading their financials from [companies house](https://www.gov.uk/get-information-about-a-company) - the UK company registry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably misunderstanding the question, but hopefully by posting this answer, I'll be able to find out what you mean to ask.

> What currency exchange rate would then be used to determine how many dollars would amount to the value of the firm?

So, you want to determine the firm's value in USD?

If you have the firm's value in EUR, then the exchange rate that would be used is the USD to EUR exchange rate. If you have the firm's value in GBP, then the exchange rate that would be used is the USD to GBP exchange rate.

Comment: Thanks for having a stab at it. I've further clarified the question. I am indeed trying to find out what the is value to me as a holder of US$, ultimately to see if it is cheaper now the exchange rate is low.